# Simple analog display?

Tags: analog, display, ultrasound

One type of analog display is the oscilloscope. A beam sweeps across the screen and voltage deflects the beam as it goes. The drawback is that it requires an electron tube, with all that that entails.

In my application we want to transmit and receive an ultrasonic pulse and then display that pulse. Obviously, this can be done with an oscilloscope. Ideally we would like to find a much simpler, cheaper device that can display the **analog** pulse. Is there such a display technology?

Comment: Ahem, I suspect most folk use a digital scope these days. What century we're you born in?

Comment: You can buy one of my Sonar Fish aka rock finders good for 100m depth, It has a 4x3" display with variable sensitivity. but 16 yrs ago I invented the first Kopin head-mounted display " the M1",  so pig farmers could see the fetus in a monocle with VGA resolution with ultrasound wand and battery pack.

Comment: What do you exactly mean "to display the analog pulse"? Is it like a regular scope voltage-time chart, or you have something different in mind?

Comment: @AliChen Right, an ultrasonic pulse can be displayed on a regular scope voltage-time. I just don't want the expense of a scope. I want a dedicated display device.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I was unable to find a description on the web of this device. Is it a fish finder? I am kind of hoping to find a simple analog way to display time-voltage that does not require a tube. I do not want to get a ADC involved.

Comment: @TylerDurden, what kind of information are seeking from the displayed chart? Time? Shape? Amplitude? Maybe you can achieve your goals in somewhat different ways, not by re-inventing a CRT?

Comment: @TylerDurden the device is called a DSO but for slim budgets a Picoscope on USB

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Way way overkill. What I want is like a substrate like zinc sulfide or something, with discrete components that cause the panel to scintillate like an oscilloscope, ie, something that costs like $1.00 in parts. No ADC.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 For example, one idea I had was to try to figure out a way to make an electrolumiscent panel to act like an oscilloscope: basically solder wires to the back of it and make a circuit with a strobe, so that it would light up like an oscilloscope when the pulse moved across it.

Comment: i don't think such  phosphor devices exist from your description. EL is only used as a backlight

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 What about using an LCD? Is there a way to gate the signal so it activates the pixels in a waveform manner without digitizing? In other words just use the signal to drive the LCD directly. Obviously it would require some kind of thresholding matrix, at least for the Y-axis. Eg you could put a progressively resistive strip against the transistor column, so that basically the LCD would act like a bar chart depending on the voltage. Would that work?

Comment: no that is way over your ability and budget

Comment: Do it like good old Edison: use a needle on a wax drum.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the pulse in analog fashion, convert to digital, and display it on an LCD display. This is far more *complex* than an analog oscilloscope needs to be- it's possible to make an oscilloscope tube display a few 10's of volts directly, using an electrostatic deflection tube such as a 3JP1, but it involves a special hard-to-find vacuum tube, filament current, high voltage and some biasing, plus the sawtooth generator and trigger for horizontal deflection (could be a few op-amps or some discretes for relatively low frequencies to a MHz or two).

But even though it's **incredibly** complex, involving millions of transistors and a fair bit of code, it's not necessarily *expensive* and one can purchase modules that do this for less than $50 US. The same technology is used in many consumer products (displays used in cell phones, GPS etc.) as are the CPUs (ARM, for example) so the parts are relatively cheap and high performance. Provided you don't need oscilloscope performance, that is. A modern digital oscilloscope does GHz sampling. You don't need that for **most** ultrasonics which is not much over audio in frequency. Of course if you're doing MHz ultrasonics you may need more sophisticated circuitry, and a real digital oscilloscope would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Modern digital technology makes this simple, easy, and inexpensive.  Far less expensive than anything with a CRT. Especially if you want to view transient events which would need a storage scope.

Is there a modern ANALOG way of doing this?  Extraordinarily unlikely given now easy it is to solve with modern digital technology.